# what is the right way to keep re-rendering component using setTimeout until prop changes in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a calendar component that asynchronously fetches the calendar events on componentDidMount. the API might return a response that says that the  calendar is unavailable right now so in that case I want the component to keep re-fetching the data every 5 seconds until it succeeds.

I tried something like

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){

  if(nextProps.data.calendarBuildStatusCode){
    this.setState({isBuildingCalendar: true});
    setTimeout(()=>{
      this.fetchEvents();
    }, 5000)
  }else{
     this.setState({isBuildingCalendar: false});
  } 
}
```

where `nextProps.data.calendarBuildStatusCode` is the indication that I get from the API that the calendar is still not available. and `this.setState({isBuildingCalendar: true});` is simply in charge of displaying a spinner until the calendar is available.

`this.fetchEvents();` is a call to the API to get the calendar events, it will cause a re-render.

The code above doesn't work (and I knew it wouldn't), I was just trying to give a sense of what I'm trying to achieve but don't know how.

Any suggestions on how to deal with re-rendering using setTimout until prop is changed would be great.

Comment: Why the downvote? Apart from hitting the poor server every 5 secs when it is already stressed :)

Comment: haters everywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to make use of `clearTimeout` and use it within your `fetchEvents` api call

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  if(nextProps.data.calendarBuildStatusCode){ // Probably you should also add a conditional check here that signifies a change in data, otherwise everytime `calendarBuildStatusCode` is `true` and `componentWillReceiveProps` is called this function will execute.
    this.timerID = setTimeout(()=>{
      this.fetchEvents();
    }, 5000)
  }
}
```

Now within the fetchEvents function

```
fetchEvents(){
   ApiCall().then(() => {
       clearTimeout(this.timerID);
   });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, clearTiemout did the trick... still not sure why got the downvote, I know hitting the server every 5 seconds isn't the optimal way, but this is what the task I got required me to do...